# Is converse of Lewy theorem true?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, harmonic-functions, several-complex-variables

In complex analysis, there is a result named Lewy's theorem, which states that:

> If $u=(u_1,u_2):\subseteq \mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ is one-one and harmonic in a neighborhood $U$ of origin $(0,0)\in \mathbb{R^2}$, then the Jacobian $J(x,y)=\left[\frac{\partial(u_1,u_2)}{\partial(x,y)}\right]$ does not vanish at the origin.

My question is: is the converse true? That is, if the Jacobian of a harmonic function $u$ does not vanish at a point , say, origin. Then is $u$ always one-one in a neighborhood of the origin?

Answer (score 0):

Is a particular case of the [Inverse function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem). Being harmonic is irrelevant except because harmonic $\implies$ $C^\infty$.